# What method would I use when data has an upper and lower boundary in GluonTS

Tags: time-series, probability, python, probabilistic-forecasts

I have a time series dataset that has a max ceiling of 50 and a lower threshold of 0, however when using probabilistic time series modeling like GluonTS I am getting future predictions that are either above 50 or in the minus which is throwing off any real predictions.

How should I proceed to preprocess the data (if GluonTS accepts this)? Or how can I fix the issue? What current methods yield the best results?